# Stack Trace of HTML page rendered in cake php

Tags: cakephp

I am a budding cake php developer and facing a problem that's eating a lot of my productive time. 
Currently, the project is in its final development stage and I was newly hired to improve/add functionality of the product. For example, I need to add functionality of about page that has huge nested ajax calls and elements. I follow the following procedure to find source code of existing functionality:
1. View the url and locate corresponding controller and action.
2. If there is no explicit render function call, locate the corresponding view
3. If the required html element's code is found, Hurray!! If not,
4. Check for any ajax calls applied on that html element in script portion of the page. If not, 
5. Check for any element function calls and navigate to the corresponding element file.
6. If still not found, check for other element calls and repeat step 3.

Now since the project is very poorly written with absolutely no trace of comments, model being the thinnest portion of project, every logic written in controller's action and each controller exceeds 2k LOC, I end up wasting too much of time just to locate source of existing code. 
I was wondering if there is any stack trace feature like in case of any exception that could show me what all functions were called in rendering the required view and each of its elements.
Please tell me if there is any feature offered by cake php or browser and if there is anything wrong in my approach.

Thanks in advance
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now since the project is very poorly written with absolutely no trace
>   of comments, model being the thinnest portion of project, every logic
>   written in controller's action and each controller exceeds 2k LOC

That project is doomed and the code garbage. I don't even have to see it, this is enough to know it. I've got this kind of garbage on my desk to "rescue" it but it wouldn't make any sense. A rewrite would be always cheaper than recycling this level of garbage.

Debugger::trace() will give you the trace from where ever you called it.

You are wasting time with your approach (Point 4) any way: You don't need to check the code for Ajax calls, every modern browser has a dev tool (press F12 in Chrome) that usually has a network tab which shows what resources are loaded from where - AJAX calls in the background as well.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me some ideal conventions such that i could repair code myself?

Comment: This is nothing that is explained in two sentences, generic rule is skinny controllers and fat models. Overall it seems the app was poorly designed if it has fat controllers. Let me guess: Duplicate code as well? For CakePHP conventions see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html